# How do I host a Node.js server on AWS cloudfront? I'm trying to make a social media

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using AWS cloudfront to store data but I need a backend (Node.js) server to upload and delete data automatically. How can I connect a node.js server to AWS cloudfront, with access to read and write its files?

Answer (score 0):

AWS CloudFront acts as a CDN (Cache and a Proxy) and you can put it in front of your Node Server. You can connect your NodeJS server (DNS) as an origin and provide caching rules as behaviors (e.g; /js/* /api/* ).

Comment: can you please share some reference, I need the same.

Comment: @SachinVairagi This is not difficult to setup. You need to host your node server and create origin + behaviors in CloudFront pointing to each url path.

Comment: thanks for your response, yes I have set it up but still think that some article or guide can help others :)